# How to add a bounty to my own question?

Tags: support, questions, bounties

possible duplicate of [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work), but I think this question is more specific, and I can not find specific help in the above link. So I posted it.

I've ask a question here. [How should C++ objects be serialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699918/how-should-c-objects-be-serialized). Now I want to give a bounty to it. I find this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty, which is right below the comment area question , a link titled "eligible for bounty in 2 days". but I could not think how it offered any help.

Comment: What do you not understand about that statement?

Comment: It tells you exactly what is going on. You need to wait for 2 days before you can offer a bounty.

Comment: And in the link (that you say is not a duplicate), did you read under the `How do I start a bounty? When can I start a bounty?` section? `A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was asked.`

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I can't find this: "To start a bounty, click on the "start a bounty" link at the bottom of an eligible question" start a bounty link.

Comment: @Oded Means I can only do it 2 days later? Thanks, very helpful!

Comment: Yes, exactly. You have to wait for 2 days after a question has first been asked before you can offer a bounty on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That link title says it all. "Eligible for bounty in 2 days". You have to wait 2 full days from the time of initially posting the question until you can offer a bounty.

Give it some time, your question has been up for 1 hour.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks.